# "rendered" usage with variable

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am trying to use "rendered" based on the two conditions below.

I have created variable called "output" to pass the value of "true" and "false" to Visualforce page.

The issue that I am having is that the first condition works, but the second condition does not work.

First condition would not display any output. It works (it does not display data).

The second condition would display output as normal. It does not work.

I am curious whether location of " output =  " inside IF Statement is causing the issue.

Bottom is APEX code:
I modified the code after.

```
        public Boolean output {get;set;} 


        // First Condition: When MRN is blank 
        if( !string.isBlank(tr.mrn))            
        {
            if (RowList.size() > 1){
                ApexPages.addMessage(
                New ApexPages.Message(
                ApexPages.Severity.FATAL, 'Multiple records found. Please try with MRN'
                ));
                return null;                       

              }
              output = false;
        }

        else
        {
          // Second Condition: When MRN is Not blank
        output = true; 
        }
```

Bottom is VF code:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!RowList}" var="c" rendered="{!output}">
            <apex:column >
                <apex:facet name="header">MRN</apex:facet>
                {!c.mrn}
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column >
                <apex:facet name="header">Last Name</apex:facet>
                {!c.lname}
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column >
                <apex:facet name="header">First Name</apex:facet>
                {!c.fname}
            </apex:column>                         
         </apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rendered="{!output}"` evaluates boolean expression.

In your code `output` is String type. Change it to Boolean like this.

```
public Boolean output {get;set;} 

// First Condition: When MRN is blank 
if( !string.isBlank(tr.mrn))            
{
    if (RowList.size() > 1){
        ApexPages.addMessage(
        New ApexPages.Message(
        ApexPages.Severity.FATAL, 'Multiple records found. Please try with MRN'
        ));
        return null;                       

      }
      output = false;
}
else
{
      // Second Condition: When MRN is Not blank
    output = true; 
}
```

Otherwise, use `rendered="{!output=='true'}"`

**Update**

According to your logic, data will be displayed in following conditions:

> When output is true, string.isBlank(tr.mrn) is blank and RowList.size() > 1

So, I think you have wrongly written the logic. According to the comment in the code, the correct logic will be as follows:

```
// First Condition: When MRN is blank 

if(string.isBlank(tr.mrn))            
{
    if (RowList.size() > 1){
        ApexPages.addMessage(
        New ApexPages.Message(
        ApexPages.Severity.FATAL, 'Multiple records found. Please try with MRN'
        ));
        return null;                       

      }
      output = false;
}
else
{
    // Second Condition: When MRN is Not blank
    output = true; 
}
```

Comment: Not sure why it still does not work. I changed to Boolean.

Comment: what is the issue? if output is true then what you are trying to display?

Comment: If the output is  true, I am trying to display the VF table with data.

Comment: check when output is true, string.isBlank(tr.mrn) is blank and RowList.size() > 1, then only data will be displayed

Comment: Not sure what you meant by "when output is true". Are you referring to on the Apex side or VF side?

Comment: check the Updated answer, your logic for output=true is wrong, you have checked first condition as null like this if(!string.isBlank(tr.mrn)) and thats why it is not satisfying

Comment: Thanks. I am still working on it, but it is logic issue.